# iOS appstore submission using xcode command line tools

Tags: ios, xcode

I have come across various articles explaining how you can build and archive an iOS application using the command line tools packaged with xcode.

Is it possible to use the tools to validate and distribute the application to the appstore?

Edit following comment: I am looking to avoid using the GUI as I have multiple similar apps, so I'm looking to script the update process to make it faster (less manual).

Comment: It just may be me, but why wouldn't you want to use Xcode graphical interface for this? Too easy?

Comment: Good question - I probably should have explained above. I have multiple apps which are all similar (clones with slightly different data), so I am looking to automate my update process via a script. The GUI functionally works fine, but the manual process is something I'm trying to speed up.

Comment: You can use the lighter-weight [Application Loader.app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/9_UsingApplicationLoader/UsingApplicationLoader.html). It's still gui, but you can use it for pre-built binaries. Pretty sure it's the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for Transporter. It's included inside Application Loader, but there's now documentation on how to use it separately: (emphasis mine)

> You can now use Transporter, Apple's command-line delivery tool, to deliver localized App Store metadata in bulk, including screenshots, rights and pricing, and more. Transporter can also find metadata for your existing apps so you can see how to correctly format the XML. **To learn more about using Transporter and providing metadata, download the Transporter User Guide and the App Metadata Specification from the [Manage Your Apps](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/manageApps) module in iTunes Connect.**

Source: [Apple News and Announcements for Developers; Aug 22, 2013](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=8222013b)

Comment: And to be clear, you can't yet publish apps with this tool, only metadata at this very second. Perhaps we'll see new features with WWDC 2014 in a few weeks.